# Run Java program with GUI from an AWS EC2 Terminal

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-ec2, vnc

I have an AWS EC2 instance that is running Ubuntu 14.04 and which I can access the OS GUI by running vncserver and then connecting to the server with a VNC (I'm using TightVNC). I have installed a java program on the server which runs just fine if I start the program while connected to the server via TightVNC.

However, what I want to do is launch the program from the terminal and then launch a script that interacts with the program via clicking on predetermined mouse co-ordinates.

When attempting to run the java program from the EC2 terminal after starting vncserver I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:68)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
```

Any advice on a decent way to accomplish what I have described would be much appreciated. Or if I have overlooked anything - please inform me what.

Comment: did you export your $DISPLAY ?

Comment: Nope I'm unfamiliar with the concept. I guess it is something I need to do to run GUI programs from terminal? @FrédéricHenri

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell x11 where the application are running.

running

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

before you call your Java program will fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately I am now having problems connecting all together. I know I can fix it but I am getting very tired. I will fix and then try this when I wake up.

Comment: ok hopefully a good night sleep and helpful answers and tomorrow will be a better day :)

Comment: Okay so I solved that issue now back to the main one.. I tried the export DISPLAY=:0 command before running the java program and I get the same error as in the original post with one difference - before that error message it prints 'No protocol specified' twice. Any idea?

Comment: can you do `echo $XAUTHORITY`, if not set run `xauth info` to find where you authority file is and then `export XAUTHORITY=<location>`

Comment: I did as you said. Here is the logs of the commands I did: http://pastebin.com/4T63zb8m still the same error

Comment: By the way - if it matters I am accessing the EC2 command line remotely with SSH